# Никому не рекомендую данный форум

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, блокировка

Я очень недоволен отношением администраторов к новичкам в этом форуме. Я впервые посещаю такие сайты, мне нужна помощь, а меня блокируют за то, что я неправильно задал вопрос. Никому не рекомендую данный форум, найдите другой.

Возможно, этот отзыв будет удалён для сохранения репутации, но тогда это пускай остаётся на совести модераторов и впредь будьте благодушнее с новичками.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните, что именно вызвало у Вас недовольство? Без объяснений сложно будет исправить ситуацию...

Comment: Да и Вас не блокировали. Вполне возможно, что это на некоторое время сделала сама система за несколько закрытых вопросов. А вопросы закрывает сообщество. Сообща. Для этого нужно целых 5 человек, причём с достаточной репутацией.

Comment: Самое большое заблуждение новичков, что этот сайт форум.  Но он **не является форумом**.

Comment: @Tg0xdb, а разве  не все равно, как этот сайт называется? Форум или не форум? Если тут помогают, значит это **хорошее место**, если нет, то всем посоветуют поискать *что-то другое*.

Comment: @avp В отличие от типичных форумов, после получения помощи, здесь ожидается, что ТС тоже приложит усилия для помощи тем, у кого может возникнуть аналогичная проблема. Если желания помочь в ответ нет, то да, лучше поискать _что-то другое_, например, какой нибудь **форум**, и как он будет называться, это всё равно.

Comment: Это не неблагодарность, те ответы, которые были даны мне, не помогли мне решить вопроса, и тогда в чем польза от таких ответов, если они не помогают, конечно, я все равно БЛАГОДАРЕН за то, что мне хотя бы ответили, но все же не стоит меня называть неблагодарным

Comment: Кто эти четверо, выдавшие +?

Comment: Не понял ваш вопрос

Comment: @αλεχολυτ я поставил плюс, т.к. слишком много ветеранов сайта негативно относятся к новичками.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik а я вот воспринимаю эти плюсы за **«Никому не рекомендую данный форум, найдите другой»**. Ну и по сути, это же просто пост негатива, который человек решил выплеснуть в качестве отзыва на сайт. С таким же успехом можно написать хвалебный пост о том, какой ruSO замечательный и тут всегда всем помогают. И такой пост тоже будет требовать закрытия, как не содержащий ничего полезного, просто развивающий споры между людьми с разными мнениями. Хочется написать отзыв — вот ссылка https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/contact.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ я уже на эту тему ругался с администрацией SE. Если я ставлю плюс, это не означает поддержку автора, это значит, что я нашёл что-то важное в сообщении. Даже в этом вопросе есть важные вещи. Я в сети очень часто вижу упоминания "токсичности ruSO". Так что в какой-то мере проблема, всё же, есть.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik нет тут ничего важного. Просто домашку в очередной раз не удалось на халяву поиметь, и, вот, бомбануло.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ конкретного у этого автора - да.

Comment: Возможно я выражусь грубо, но у кого в черепной коробке присутствует мозг, на SO останется, понимая, что это замечательный ресурс, не столкнувшись с токсичностью в свою сторону. Остальные же шлют сюда в качестве вопросов заказы на сайт под ключ и вполне закономерно должны столкнуться с сопротивлением)

Comment: К примеру я: впервые начал работать полтора месяца назад, а около двух недель назад решил зарегистрироваться здесь, ожидая, что лучше бы мне изучить ресурс, потому что очень скоро мне возможно придется задать впервые здесь вопрос, а не просто находить его в строке браузера)
Но каждый раз, когда я хотел уже оформить вопрос, я в попытках извлечь максимальное количество деталей, находил новые вопросы для гугла и в итоге просто решал этот вопрос сам. Уже 2 недели я залип, отвечая на вопросы, не задавая их, набивая при этом репутацию. И как-то с токсиком не сталкивался вообще.

Answer (score 14):

1. Перед тем, как обвинять администрацию/модераторов, советую ознакомиться со справкой. Как минимум, про то, как [создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
2. Хорошо бы ознакомиться с правилами. Как минимум, после закрытия [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1104331/15479) вопроса стоило бы почитать статью про [закрытые вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions), чтобы понять, что с вашими вопросами не так.
3. Ну и последнее - блокировки на написание вопросов/ответов вешает система автоматически. У модераторов нету таких возможностей.

Answer (score 14):

Не вы первый, не вы последний, кто бегает с сайта на сайт, заявляя, что тут плохо, уйду от вас.

Я уже много лет являюсь довольно активным участником нескольких форумов программистов (или являлся, т. к. они уже закрыты). И многие здешние активные пользователи аналогично (их <strike>рожи</strike> ники знакомы по тем форумам).

Так вот регулярно на всех этих сайтах появляются такие как вы: "Мне не помогли, не сделали за меня домашнюю работу, вы плохие..." И человек бежит на другой сайт клянчить там.

При этом одновременно с другого сайта прибегает другой, которому (якобы) не помогли там и клянчит здесь. Так сказать, круговорот нубов в интернете.

Если бы вы сами отвечали на вопросы, то знали бы, что часто почти одновременно появляются прямо противоположные сообщения от разных пользователей: "Ваш сайт плохой, ухожу", "Ваш сайт лучший, только здесь мне помогли". Первому не повезло - никто в данный момент на захотел в сотый раз отвечать на элементарный вопрос, ответы на который давно имеются. Второму повезло: ему кто-то сделал лабу.

Comment: Кстати, с этим я согласен. Я вот тоже периодически недоволен, что мои вопросы закрывают на SO. Но как можно жаловаться, что тут вообще не помогают (не по конкретному вопросу, а вообще), имея при этом 78% отвеченных вопросов??

Comment: Во-первых, я на вашем сайте(если не форуме) в поисковике пытался найти ответ на мой вопрос, но я не нашел ответа. Во-вторых, я не бегал с другого форума к вам, поэтому вы здесь просто так обвинили меня в этом. А в-третьих, я написал отзыв для того, чтобы ваш сайт стал лучше. Ну откуда я мог знать, что чтобы нормально выделить программный код, нужно нажать сочетание клавиш Ctrl+K, узнав об этом только тогда, когда появилось нарушение. Я не знал о такой функции, а если бы знал, то конечно пользовался бы.

Comment: И кстати про принятия ответов я тоже не имел понятия

Comment: @Tiranich поэтому на сайте есть [справка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help), с которой (хотя бы по диагонали) стоило ознакомиться прежде, чем ругать сайт.

Answer (score 11):

На 7 вопросов из 10 (а по сути из 9) получил ответы, ни одного не принял.
И недоволен при этом о_О

[image: скриншот списка заданных вопросов]

Comment: А разве вопрос с ответом не мог быть автоматически удалён системой, так как имел неположительный рейтинг и был закрыт?

Comment: С содержанием отчасти согласен, но форма поста не очень дружелюбная.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, да, я ошибся, вопрос удалён Духом. Автором удалён только другой вопрос, но он копия следующего, на который дан ответ.

Comment: Сообщение было опубликовано в качестве ответа, но оно **не содержит ответа на вопрос**. Сообщение может быть правкой, едким комментарием, другим вопросом, но, возможно, его стоит просто удалить.

Comment: Также напомню, что принятие ответов, хоть и очень желательно, но не является обязательным. Нету же в правилах и штрафах такого, что за 20 вопросов без единого принятого ответа система блокирует задание новых вопросов?

Comment: Я недоволен потому что ни один из этих ответов не помог мне, поэтому если вы не знаете всех подробностей, то лучше не стоит меня просто так обвинять

Comment: Больше на комментарий тянет)

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik это можно сказать о множестве "ответов" Qwertiy на мете, имхо.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ замечаю периодически. Но яро в этом плане мету не модерирую. Особого вреда от такого вроде нету.

Answer (score -2):

- Это не форум (a Q&A site).
- Чтобы получить хороший ответ, задайте хороший вопрос.
- Прочитайте справку, прежде чем задавать вопрос и ругаться на модерацию, которая вообще ни в чем не виновата.
- Ответы вам были даны отличные, не надо гнать.

Ну и "бежать" вам особо некуда, других нормальных сообществ по программированию нет ;). А сообщества для нубов, с нубами, написанные нубами годятся только для нубов.